# Can we express Java date in this form 2016-02-02T10:40:54.264880?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have to create date string from Java date in the form as given below

**2016-02-02T10:40:54.264880**

Does **SimpleDateFormat** class allows formatting date in the above format ?

If it does then what is the format string for this ?

I tried using this **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"** but cannot generate the required string.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you've got a `Z` at the end of your format string, and you're only formatting to milliseconds despite your goal being microseconds. What version of Java are you using? The `java.util.Date`-based API only has a precision of milliseconds, so if you need microseconds, you're going to have troubles...

Comment: @JonSkeet Question's tagged Android, so that means no Java 8 Time API.

Comment: @chrylis: Ah, had missed that. In which case, the OP really needs to explain how they're expecting to get microsecond precision.

Comment: @JonSkeet So we cannot do with java.util.Date . 
 Thanks.

Comment: yes @chrylis using Java 7 and was trying to do in an Android app.

Comment: Well you could format a `java.util.Date` to 6 decimal places... it's just that the final 3 digits won't be useful information. For example, you could format a value to 2016-02-02T10:40:54.264000.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually problem occurred while integrating client library for GAE api end points whose backend was in python.

Comment: That doesn't really help us know how you want to handle the extra data... if you're happy losing the microsecond precision, it's easy to *either* format to millisecond precision, *or* to format to microsecond precision but with made-up values for the final 3 digits. However, you should be aware that data won't roundtrip in that case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that makes sense. Let me lose the microsecond precision and do it your way. Thanks.

Comment: FYI this format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Both Joda-Time and java.time frameworks use ISO 8601 formats as their defaults in parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

Answer (score 1):

Use yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS and that will give you precision up to milli seconds. Java 8 time package can provide you nano seconds precision, which is not available in util Date

Comment: Thanks . Will try as suggested in comments under question.

Comment: @Napolean Please post an Answer showing your solution. Then accept that Answer to mark this Question as closed.

Comment: @BasilBourque Going to do at that first place.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this to maintain the format along with losing precision for microseconds.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String commentDate = sdf.format(new Date())+"000";
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

If Android moves to Java 8 technology ([may be in the works](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/01/android-n-switches-to-openjdk-google-tells-oracle-it-is-protected-by-the-gpl/)), you can use the java.time framework.

### Nanoseconds

These classes support finer granularity, nanoseconds rather than the milliseconds of java.util.Date & Joda-Time. That is more than enough for the microseconds in your input string.

### ISO 8601

These classes default to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by your input string.

### `Instant`

In java.time, an `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. Its default `toString` implementation prints any fractional second number as 0, 3, 6, or 9 digits as needed by the particular value. In the case of your string that means six digits.

### UTC

I will assume your string was intended for UTC rather than some particular time zone.

### Example Code

```
 Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2016-02-02T10:40:54.264880" + "Z" );
```

> 2016-02-02T10:40:54.264880Z

## Joda-Time

Until Java 8 technology becomes available, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

Like java.time, Joda-Time use ISO 8601 formats by default.

Unlike java.time, Joda-Time has milliseconds resolution. That means a maximum of 3 digits of fractional second. You will need to truncate your six digits to three, thereby losing a bit of data.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString();
```

Similar to java.time code above:

```
 Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2016-02-02T10:40:54.264880" + "Z" );
```

The fractional second is truncated after three digits, limited to milliseconds. So you will experience loss of data as microseconds are cut to milliseconds. In this example we lose the `880`.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
```

> instant: 2016-02-02T10:40:54.264Z